# Maven repository inheritance and override

Tags: maven, repository, pom.xml

I have a Maven project that was built a few years back, and now I need to make some updates.  One of the dependencies to my project has a Maven repository listed in its POM that no longer exists.  I get build failures now.

I would have thought the repository listings in my POM or Settings.xml would trump any repositories listed in a dependency's POM; or Maven would try my repositories after failing to connect to the extinct repository.  Instead, it just bombs out with a build failure.

Additionally, I already have the required dependencies in my local repository.  I would have additionally thought that Maven would just use that.

Is there a way to override the inherited repository listings, or tell Maven to carry-on in the case of a repo problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the artifact that you depend on is a snapshot version then maven will check for a new snapshot every time you build, thats why it is a good practice to lock down your dependencies to a released version.

You can "override" the repository declarations by defining a `<mirror>` in the settings.xml.

See http://maven.apache.org/settings.html#Mirrors

I usually set up a locally hosted repository manager (preferably [nexus](http://nexus.sonatype.org/)) and then define mirrorOf(*) = local-repo-manager/url.
Nexus allows multiple repo's to be grouped with a predefined search order.
Nexus repo's can be locally hosted or caching/proxies to public repo's.
I usually have a locally hosted 3rd party repo at the front of the group, where I can store artifacts that are not published on public repo's.